# Excel how to insert data based upon criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel work sheet called Contacts.xlsx with **Sheet1** (the main sheet) with 496 contacts and a variety contact details (A:U) that include:

Zip codes (populated) Column I

Latitude (empty) Column J

Required (empty) Column K

(The numbers are negative or positive , not north, south east or west, ie latitude -35.28, longitude 149.12)

-

**Sheet2** has a list that allocates latitude and longitude to a zip zode:

Zip code is column A2:A16743

Latitude is Column D2:D16743

Longitude is Column E2:E16743

-

(All the columns have headers.)

For the various zip codes in What would the formula be to copy the corresponding latitude for each zip from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1?

And I assume I would need a second formula for longitudes?

I have c&p the first 40, but there has to be a easier (aka smarter) way!

Thank you for your assistance, Dave

EDIT: 
In response to Kevin Anthony Oppegaard Rose, suggestion to lookup VLOOKUP --
 after looking up VLOOKUP this is the formula I have been attempting and had been trying to use for a few hours before asking the question. As can be seen by the answer below I was trying to over complicate the formula.

=IF(I2=Sheet1!D1, VLOOKUP(Sheet1!D2, Sheet1!$D2:$F16743, 2), "FALSE")

A big thanks to PeterH for his assistance!

Comment: Please look into VLOOKUP formula. Give it a try, if you cant get it to work then come back and post some sample data along with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below for Lat (**On Row 2**):

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet2!A:E,4,FALSE)
```

And the below for Long:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet2!A:E,5,FALSE)
```

If you have records with no Zip code, you can say what to do in this instance:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet2!A:E,5,FALSE),"Zip Code Not Found")
```

Replace `"Zip Code Not Found"` for what you want displayed if there is no match.

For both formulas drag them down to populate the full list.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks PeterH, I was trying to over-complicate my formula. I had attempted putting something together before asking my question as it was working.

Comment: @Dave happy to help, accept as correct answer if it is now solved

Comment: ( ... to clarify, the sentence above. It should have said. I had attempted putting something together before asking my question as it (the formula) was NOT working. )